# How to fix: SAP Cloud Platform Login window renders blank in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I created a webpage with SAPUI5 that is hosted on the SAP Cloud Platform. This webpage is now in use inside an iframe as a chrome extension.
When the user is logged into the Cloud Platform everything works as intended. But if that is not the case, the server responds with the SAP Cloud Platform Login page, which is not rendered in the iframe (The html/js is loaded, as seen on the console). The Login page shows up normaly when opened in a popup for example.

My first thought was that they blocked viewing in iframes, but they didn't include such headers (*X-Frame-Options*) and as seen the code still gets loaded. I also did not find any attributes to allow the iframe to load after (what I assume is a redirect). Other pages work fine inside the iframe.

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "An Extension to test stuff",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

index.html:

```html
<html>
  <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <iframe src="https://linkedinaddin-ae467d79e.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/" width="400" height="500"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the SAP Login page to render correctly inside the iframe? Or are there any other solutions to show a webpage inside the chrome extension. I saw chrome *webview* in another solution but it seems those only work in chrome apps and not extensions.

Thank you for your help!